# Extract filenames that matches the pattern and remove duplicates and store in an array

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I would like to know the easiest way to list a part of filenames without any duplication present in a directory.

Example:

A directory has files like this:

```
Stack1_over_flow.txt
Stack2_exchange.txt
Meta_stack.txt
Stack1_over_flow.txt
Meta_stack.txt
```

Now I want the result to be:

```
Stack1
Stack2
Meta
```

Here, extract the string that occurs before the first occurrence of "_" and remove if any duplication of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls -1 | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[1]}' | sort -b | uniq
```

Only files, with find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[1]}' | sort -b | uniq
```

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting a single line command with minimum bash calls. It works !

Comment: Should work. I would recommend using a sort before the uniq just to make sure the results are actually unique. This would otherwise not be guaranteed if you were to choose something other than a prefix.

Comment: But is there a way to try with sed instead of awk ?

Comment: @Langdon Yes - see other answer.

Comment: @accurate_respondetur :The command lists even when directories are present. Is it possible to list only the files and not directories ?

Comment: Hi, i updated it to listing only files, but using find cause i don't know if it posible only with ls

Answer (score 1):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
ls -l | sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z0-9])_.*/\1/' | uniq
```

Comment: The command instead of displaying the string before the first occurrence of "_", it displays the complete file name.

Comment: works :) But it displays the directories too even when the directory name doesn't have "_". Is it possible to display only files ?

Comment: @Langdon you could replace `ls -l` with `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`

Answer (score 1):

you can even try this

```
ls -1 | cut -d "_" -f1 | uniq
```